# How to grab Realm in AIDE

Tags: android, realm, aide

I just want to pick up Realm library to my project in AIDE. I did all as it is described on official site of Realm, but AIDE doesn't react on this changes in Gradle.

Project level build.gradle:

```
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.3.1"
```

App level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

AIDE team isn't responsible in their Google+ community. Please, could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AIDE doesn't support annotation processing (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ide/KXBhxfoO0h8) which is used heavily by Realm Java.

Comment: It seems to be related to 2015 year. SupressLint and NonNull work. Will it not support custom annotations from Realm? Did you check it?

Comment: @Daimonium The last post in the thread indicated that annotations weren't support. I didn't dive into it.

Comment: You was right. I sent request to AIDE developers. Will hope, annotations will be in the next release.  Seems like you are from Realm support. AIDE have very poor support of gradle. Are you really not providing jar? 

Comment: With v1.0.0 and later we only support  Android Studio - we did really have any request for jar files and everybody was moving to Android Studio. Even with a jar file, it might be hard to get AIDE running. Realm also depends on bytecode manipulations. I also wrote to AIDE support but I haven't got a reply yet.

Comment: Wow, Realm really have very good support team. AIDE Team should take lead from you.  I hope, users of AIDE will get ability to bring cool Realm to their projects soon.

Answer (score -1):

It should be a comment which i cannot. Menu->More->Project->Refresh Build.

Comment: Nothing happened. AIDE don't want to download Realm. I read that Realm doesn't support Maven... Is there a way by which I can bring Realm manually?